# How to pass a parameter from request to DRL file in optaplanner?

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I need to pass a parameter from request to the DRL file. I need to call a method of java class that takes a parameter but I am not able to access the parameter in DRL.

Can you provide a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

From which request? a HTTP request? the loaded dataset?

Before you call `Solver.solve(planningProblem)`, do something like `planningProblem.getParametrization().setFoo("bar")`. In the DRL, you can then do something like this:

```
when
    Parametrization($foo : foo) // Parametrization is a singleton
    ...
    MyEntity(methodOnMyEntity($foo) == true)
then
    ...
```

See the source code of the Examination example.

Comment: From HttpRequest i want to get the parameter in drl file.

Comment: Is this the way to get the parameters from HttpRequest ?

Comment: Not able to solve the problem after using this solution.

Comment: Used this piece of code :  Parameterization($usersAvailability : usersAvailability) in drl file and Parameterization parametrization = new Parameterization();
parametrization.setUsersAvailability(usersAvailability);
  solution.setParameterization(parametrization); before solver.solve()

Comment: Can you help me out as i am stuck on it.

Comment: Take a look at [ServletRequest.getParameter(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: I can get the param in java code and also set it up in planning solution but when trying to get it in DRL file not able to get it? Do you have any idea about it?